# Adding Azure AD authentication To Existing MVC application That Uses Individual Accounts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I have an existing MVC application that authenticates users using their Google, Facebook or Microsoft (live) accounts. The application is derived from the basic MVC template, and the 'Individual Accounts' option was chosen. This all works fine.

We have had a request/requirement that we also support Microsoft Work Accounts, authenticated against Azure AD. We have developed a second test MVC application, using the 'Organisational Accounts' from the template and can successfully get the user details, including extended details such as Manager and Office from AD.

However we are struggling to understand how to combine the two options, and still get the extended details. We've added a OpenIdConnect option in the Startup.Auth file, pointing to AAD and they works, getting hold of the users main login only. We are struggling to then use that email to obtain the user's full information

Comment: You should probably show some code and point out what you are trying to do there and what is not working :)

Comment: did u find solution, if yes pls share the sample code.